# Hive json data explode option not exploding array

Tags: arrays, json, hadoop, hive, explode

I am inserting Json data into Hive. this is the format -

```
A1 Array <
struct <
        product array <
                     struct < 
                             dim1 array < struct <> >
                             dim2 array < struct <> >
                            >
                      >
       >>
```

In the from table clause i am using explode as :

```
Lateral view outer explode(A1.product) t1 as prod Lateral view outer explode(prod.dim1) t2 as prod_d1 Lateral view outer explode(prod.dim2) t3 as prod_d2
```

Sample data :

```
A1["product":[{"productsku":"p_dmf_qs:click: page load","v2productname":"Quality Score - click: page load","v2productcategory":"DMF","productvariant":"(not set)","productbrand":"xxxx","productrevenue":"1000","localproductrevenue":null,"productprice":"100","productquantity":"1","productrefundamount":null,"productlistname":"(not set)","dim1":[],"dim2":[]}]]
```

when i call t2 and t3 in the select statement as prod_d1 and prod_d2, i am getting a struct in the result, not array. 
Please help me. It is a nested struct. If i did not have the first product array, i could have referred this easily as A1.dim1 and A1.dim2 as two explode functions. Kindly help me out.

Comment: Please add the table definition + small data sample (few rows)

Comment: Updated sample data in my question. Kindly check.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
select  t2.dim1,t2.dim2
...
Lateral view outer inline  (A1)         t1
Lateral view outer inline  (t1.product) t2
```

Comment: Thanks Dudu.. even if i use t2.dim1 and t2.dim2, i am not addressing one array (the dim1 and dim2 array). In the table i get the result as [], which means one array is left out. we are addressing A1's array with t1 and product's array with t2 but dim1 and dim2 's ? thats where i am stuck

Comment: If you'll explode both arrays you'll get a product join